# strange behavior while parsing tab separated file in python

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I am parsing a tab separated file where the first element is a twitter hashtag and the second element is the tweet contents.

My input file looks like:

```
#trumpisanabuser    of young black men . calling for the execution of the innocent !url "
#centralparkfiv of young black men . calling for the execution of the innocent !url "
#trumppence16   "
#trumppence16   "
#america2that   @user "
```

and My code does is to filter out the duplicate contents such as retweets by checking if the second tab-sepearted element is a duplicate.

```
import sys
import csv

tweetfile = sys.argv[1]
tweetset = set()
with open(tweetfile, "rt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
    for row in reader:
       print("hashtag: " + str(row[0]) + "\t" + "tweet: " + str(row[1]))
       row[1] = row[1].replace("\\ n", "").rstrip()
       if row[1] in tweetset: 
          continue  
       temp = row[1].replace("!url","")
       temp = temp.replace("@user","")
       temp = "".join([c if c.isalnum() else "" for c in temp])
       if temp: 
           taglines.append(row[0] + "\t" + row[1])
       tweetset.add(row[1])
```

However, the parsing is done weird. When I print each parsed item, the output is as the following. Can anyone explain why the parsing breaks and caused this line to be printed (`hashtag: #trumppence16  tweet:`, newline, then `#trumppence16`)?

```
hashtag: #centralparkfive   tweet: of young black men . calling for the execution of the innocent !url "
hashtag: #trumppence16  tweet: 
#trumppence16   
hashtag: #america2that  tweet: @user "
```

Comment: you have unterminated quotes in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lines with `"` for the tweet. CSV can *quote* columns by quoting them with `"` around the value, including newlines. Everything from the opening `"` to the next closing `"` is a single column value.

You can disable quote handling by setting the [`quoting` option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting) to [`csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE):

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```